# How to exact stretch a Menu Control to the TabHeader in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

Following XAML code is for your testing needs.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
x:Name="MainWindow" Title="MainWindow" 
Height="200" Width="300">

<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Height="40" Width="50" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Menu Height="40" Width="50" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                    <MenuItem Height="40" Width="50" Header="File" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="Red">
                        <MenuItem Header="About"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Print"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Label Content="No content here because this Tab will not use."/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="40" Width="50" Header="Spain" IsSelected="True">
            <Label Content="Some content for Spain"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="40" Width="50" Header="France">
            <Label Content="Some content for France"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="40" Width="50" Header="Italy">
            <Label Content="Some content for Italy"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Question Picture: https://prnt.sc/imvkfk

I tried following link but it doesnt work.

http://www.techerator.com/2011/05/how-to-stretch-a-menu-control-to-the-width-of-a-window-in-wpf/

P.S. I want exact stretch. I want User is not able to click TabHeader with mouse anyway.

Comment: There is some language barrier confusion. Are your trying to stretch your Menu across the whole TabItem while making it so only the "File" text of the MenuItem opens the menu?

Comment: @Tronald Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am slightly confused on what you are trying to achieve still, but are you trying something like this? Replace the code for your first TabItem with this. Let me know if this is what you want. If it's not just explain further and we can make adjustments.

```
<TabItem Height="40" Width="50" Margin="-3" Padding="0">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Grid  Height="100" Width="100">
                    <Menu Margin="0" Padding="0">
                        <MenuItem Header="File" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="Red">
                            <MenuItem Header="About"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Print"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </Grid>

            </TabItem.Header>
            <Label Content="No content here because this Tab will not use."/>
</TabItem>
```

I simply wrapped your Menu in a grid for a little but more control.

Comment: Can you click anywhere on the Tab and have the Tab change, or just in certain areas? It's behaving different for me and I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: I did notice if I click the bottom of the Tab it still changes.  I edit the TabItem Margin to -3 to hide the clickable area. I don't like this solution, but it works on my end. If you are still able to click the Tab, could your tell me what version of Windows you are using?